# Having a problem with the state not being transferred to another component

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem that the value made by one component cannot be delivered to another component. I made a state in the top component and I think I connected it well. But the desired array made of state is empty. Sorry for the long code to ask.

The code below is the top component, and `InCart` is the state that I'm having issues with.

**App.js:**

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Site from './Site/Site';
import { useState } from 'react';
import RealCart from './RealCart/RealCart';


function App() {

  const [Inproducts,setInproducts] = useState([])
  const [InCart, setInCart] = useState([]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/realCart' element={<RealCart InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart}/>} />
        <Route path='/loginHome' element={<Site InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart} Inproducts={Inproducts} setInproducts={setInproducts}/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There are many components connected in the middle, so I omitted it, but the props are connected as well. And I got the json file from here.

**Section5Bottom.jsx:**

```js
import axios from 'axios';
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import "../section5.css";
    import Section5Card from './Section5Card';
    
    function Section5Bottom({Inproducts, setInproducts, InCart, setInCart}) {
    
      
      useEffect (()=> {
        axios.get("/data/products.json").then((data)=>{
          setInproducts(data.data.products);
        });
      },[setInproducts]);
    
      return (
        <div id='Section5Bottom'>
          {
            Inproducts.map((product)=>{
              return <Section5Card key={`key-${product.id}`} product={product} InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart}/>
            })
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Section5Bottom;
```

When I clicked the icon below the file, I used the `InCart` made in App.js to put the array value of the selected card in the array. If I check the console here, the array is good as shown in this photo.

[image: console showing proper array]

**Section5Card.jsx:**

```js
import '../section5.css';
import {FaCartPlus} from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import './card.css';

function Section5Card({product, InCart, setInCart}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCart = () => {
    const cartItem = {
      id : product.id,
      image : product.image,
      provider : product.provider,
      price : product.price,
      name : product.name
    }
    setInCart([...InCart, cartItem])
  }



  return (
   <div>
    <div id='CardWrap'>
          <div>
            <img id='Section5CardImg' src={product.image} />
          </div>
          //************************************
          <div>
            <FaCartPlus size='20' style={{color:'black', position:'relative', top:'124px', left:'130px', cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={()=>{dispatch({type:"ADD"}); handleCart()}} />
          </div>  
          //*************************************      
          <div id='CardBot'>
            <div id='CardBotBPrice'>
              ₩{product.price}
            </div>
            <div id='CardBotTag'>
              {product.people?
              <span id='CardBotTagPeople'>
                {product.people}명
              </span>:
              <>
                <span id='CardBotTagSale'>
                  {product.sale}
                </span>
              </>}            
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>  
   </div>
  )
}

export default Section5Card;
```

And the below file is the one I wish to bring up in the `InCart` state. But even if I check with the console, the array is empty as shown below:

[image: console showing empty array]

**RealCart.jsx:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Top from '../Site/Header/Top'
import Navi from '../Site/Header/Navi/Navi'
import Cart from './Components/Cart';
import CartHeader from './Components/CartHeader';

function RealCart(InCart, setInCart) {

  console.log(InCart)

  return (
    <div>
      <Top />
      <Navi />
      <Cart />
      <CartHeader />
    </div>
  )
}

export default RealCart;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `({InCart, setInCart})` in your `RealCart` param declaration?

Comment: Sorry, I made a simple mistake. Thank you so much for letting me know!

Comment: Have a good time in React :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your RealCart.jsx file you have to wrap your props with {} and it will be like

```
function RealCart({InCart, setInCart}) {

console.log(InCart)

return (
 <div>
  <Top />
  <Navi />
  <Cart />
  <CartHeader />
 </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a simple mistake. Thank you so much for letting me know!